# Почему такой большой bundle.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

изучаю `reactjs` на этом примере: https://metanit.com/web/react/5.3.php

размер получаемого файла:

- `bundle.js` - 897 kB
- `bundle.min.js` - 271 kB

само приложение отображает простенькую форму, с минимум функционала

у меня в других проектах в 100 kB влезают значительно более сложные приложения на AngularJS или Native JavaScript

почему такие огромные выходные файлы?

можно ли их как то сократить?

`UPDATE`

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "reduxapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "lite-server"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.21.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "immutable": "^3.7.6",
    "react": "^0.14.7",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.7",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.1",
    "redux": "^3.3.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: NODE_ENV=production  ????

Comment: @xFloooo, да. И `webpack -p`

Comment: react + react-dom = 140. 130 свободно может быть большое приложение. Или же Вы подключаемые либы секомпилировали в один бандл + возможно и css с его либами. А ещё возможно вфигачили что-то от babel полифилы которого по размеры как раз бы и подошли.

Comment: и мне кажется что не очень здорово все в один бандл собирать.

Comment: @OlmerDale, если есть опыт, какой размер `bundle.min` будет нормальным в серьезном проекте (без CSS) ? мне тоже кажется что как минимум CSS надо держать отдельно

Comment: css компилирую отдельно, по возможности разбиваю для каждого роута в свой отдельный файл + общий для всех. Минимальный проектик который у меня есть 70кБ.min, он вообще без роута классический spa с одной страницей. Но писал сам с нуля. А максимальный, я думаю без встроенного svg для одного роута не думаю чтобы больше 100 кБ весил, да и то это много.

Comment: @OlmerDale, а Вы `react` и `react-dom` не используете? в вопрос добавил  `package.json`, CSS в коде нет, что еще кроме `react` и `react-dom` могло раздуть проект?

Comment: @OlmerDale, как для каждого роута делать свой `bundle` ? или я Вас не правильно понял?

Comment: использую и то и тдругое, но не компилирую их в общий бандл. Нет, поняли правильно, можно для каждого роута сделать свой бандл и даже грузить потом только для актуального. Но это очень большая тема которая охватывает сразу целую охапку технологий и вот так просто это не объяснишь. Из всего перечисленного я immutable не работал и не знаю её вес. Сами смотрите и считайте. Babel добавляется в том случаи если Вы его напрямую в коде подключаете. Вы или тот кто генератор проекта писал. Инлайн стили ещё + инлайн картинки и инлайн svg.

Comment: @OlmerDale, объясните как исключить `react` и `react-dom` из `bundle` ?

Comment: Нехочу:) В гугле полно информации как это сделать. читайте о externals

Comment: OK ) а что почитать про разделение бандлов по роутингам, какие ключевые термины искать? что то меня все время на `react-routes` кидает

Comment: все что касается сборки относится только к webpack.